# When queries start executing on standby server the replay lag starts to increase

Tags: postgresql, replication, high-availability, master-slave-replication, troubleshooting

I have a two servers with following specs:

- 8 vCPU, 32768 MB RAM, 640 GB SSD

The master Postgres 13.3 database (db1) is installed on first server (Ubuntu 16.04.7) with the following config:

```
shared_buffers = 16GB 
work_mem = 128MB
maintenance_work_mem = 8GB
effective_cache_size = 16GB

effective_io_concurrency = 400
max_worker_processes = 8
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 4
max_parallel_workers = 8

wal_level = logical
synchronous_commit = on
max_wal_size = 4GB
min_wal_size = 32MB
wal_keep_size = 16384
wal_sender_timeout = 60s
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.7

synchronous_standby_names = 'FIRST 1 (db2_slave)'
max_standby_archive_delay = 1800s
max_standby_streaming_delay = 1800s
```

The standby is a Postgres 13.4 database (db2) installed on second server (Ubuntu 20.04.3) with the following config:

```
shared_buffers = 24GB
work_mem = 128MB
maintenance_work_mem = 16GB
effective_cache_size = 24GB

effective_io_concurrency = 400
max_worker_processes = 8
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 4
max_parallel_workers = 8

wal_level = logical
synchronous_commit = on
max_wal_size = 4GB
min_wal_size = 32MB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.7

primary_conninfo = 'host=... port=5432 user=repluser passfile=''...'' application_name=db2_slave'
primary_slot_name = 'db2'
hot_standby = on
max_standby_archive_delay = 1800s
max_standby_streaming_delay = 1800s
```

If I run iotop -u postgresql on the standby, I see two processes:

```
2229172 postgres: 13/main: walreceiver streaming DDFD/8E9FE9E0
2229138 postgres: 13/main: startup recovering 000000010000DDFD0000008E
```

After I run **read request which takes a few seconds** on the standby (`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM big_table;`), the walreceiver streaming continues to work, but the replica stops syncing:

```
2229138 postgres: 13/main: startup recovering 000000010000DE0400000017 waiting
```

I ran this query on master:

```
SELECT client_addr                                                       as client,
       usename                                                           as user,
       application_name                                                  as name,
       state,
       sync_state                                                        as mode,
       pg_size_pretty(pg_wal_lsn_diff(pg_current_wal_lsn(), sent_lsn))   as pending,
       pg_size_pretty(pg_wal_lsn_diff(sent_lsn, write_lsn))              as write,
       pg_size_pretty(pg_wal_lsn_diff(write_lsn, flush_lsn))             as flush,
       pg_size_pretty(pg_wal_lsn_diff(flush_lsn, replay_lsn))            as replay,
       pg_size_pretty(pg_wal_lsn_diff(pg_current_wal_lsn(), replay_lsn)) as total_lag
FROM pg_stat_replication;
```

And the output was:

```
   client    |   user   |   name    |   state   | mode | pending |  write  |  flush  | replay | total_lag 
-------------+----------+-----------+-----------+------+---------+---------+---------+--------+-----------
 ...         | repluser | db2_slave | streaming | sync | 0 bytes | 0 bytes | 0 bytes | 21 MB  | 21 MB
(1 row)
```

If I execute this request several times, the replay and total lag increases all the time during execution this query (`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM big_table`).
Therefore, I want to know the answers to the questions:

1. Why does the replay lag keep increasing during the execution of an analytical query for replica?
2. Why is the recovery process in the "waiting" state as soon as I start a request to the standby?

Comment: Check wait_event from pg_stat_activity

Comment: @jjanes Before run query:  `pid: 2346897, backend_type: startup, wait_event_type: Activity, wait_event: RecoveryWalStream` After: `pid: 2346897, backend_type: startup, wait_event_type: IPC, wait_event: RecoveryConflictSnapshot`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason are *recovery conflicts*. The database can either delay replication or cancel the conflicting query. This is governed by the `max_standby_streaming_delay` parameter on the standby, which determines how long PostgreSQL is ready to delay replay of the replicated information before canceling the offending query.

You can reduce the number of conflicts by setting `hot_standby_feedback` to `on` on the standby (at the risk of bloating tables on the primary), but that won't get rid of the problem completely.

Essentially, you will not be able to run uninterrupted queries on the standby and have no replication lag at the same time.

See [my article on the topic](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/streaming-replication-conflicts-in-postgresql/) for details.

Answer (score 0):

> wait_event: RecoveryConflictSnapshot

The replay needs to remove a tuple which the query running the count is still entitled to see.  So replay will wait.

Comment: `big_table` is a static table, there are no delete/update requests for this table.

Comment: That doesn't matter. A snapshot is a snapshot, there is no such thing as a table-specific snapshot.

Comment: You said that "The replay needs to remove a tuple". Why did you decide that "the replay needs to remove a tuple", if there are no updates or deletions on this table, and vacuum is not running?

Comment: I said the tuple to be removed was entitled to be visible to the snapshot, I didn't say what table it was being removed from.  As I said, there are no table-specific snapshots.  PostgreSQL does not currently try to predict which tables a snapshot will try to access in the future.